# Is it permissible to break a fast if I am travelling?

Tags: ramadan, sawm, travelling

I used to fast daily and I have kept all fasts except one. I had left a fast because I was travelling about 150km away from my hometown. A relative of mine used to ask me that how many fasts have I kept and I used to tell them that I have kept all the fasts and I do so because I had intended to perform the fast I left due to travelling as Qaza.

So, did I say something wrong or am I committing a sin? 
I am confused, can someone guide me?

Comment: Explain whether you told them "after" having fasted for the missed fast or before that? In the latter case it looks like you weren't truthful, though subject to whether your telling them was deliberate or spontaneous.

Answer (score 1):

About the qada' (qaza) this is clear  according to the Verse 185 in surat al-Baqara

> [2:185] Ramadan is the month in which the Qur'an was sent down : this
>   Book is a perfect guidance for mankind and consists of clear teachings
>   which show the right way and are a criterion of Truth and falsehood.
>   Therefore from now on whoever witnesses it, it is obligatory on hire
>   to fast the whole month,
>
> *but if one be ill or on a journey, he should make up for the same number by fasting on other days.*
>
> Allah desires to show leniency to you and does not desire to show any
>   hardship. "therefore this method is being shown to you so that you may
>   complete the number of Fast days and glorify Allah for the Guidance He
>   has shown to you and be grateful to Him

And it is/was your right to break fast as you had a permission from Allah. Some madhabs may say one should try to fast or it's better to fast and others will even say you should take the opportunity of having a permission from Allah!

The only sin i can see is that if i got you right, you lied to your relatives from a fiqh point of view this won't break your fast it is still safe, but you have loosen *tawab* and *ajr* (rewards). To me it's not clear why you lied? because you had a permission not to fast!

I hope i could help!

Comment: no brother i did not break my fast and nor did i lie. i just said i have kept all fasts but the fast that i left was just due to travelling and ALLAH says that a traveller can do his fasts as qaza am i right

Comment: maybe it can be accounted as shortening rather than lying...

Comment: @hamzajarral here "but the fast that i left was just due to travelling" looks like in contents of what you told, but in the question "I do so because I have intended to ...." looks like it is outside of what you told, but what you say additionally only us. maybe you do not know english well.