# Skip fast due to office team outing?

Tags: sawm, ramadan

I am supposed to attend a team outing at office next week. It is a full day activity and we will start for the destination in the morning and return back in evening. The destination is 40 kilometers away and I will be driving.

My question is - Is this a valid reason to skip fast? Is it okay to skip the fast on this day and make up for it later?

Comment: I'm driving each day 110km just to go to office (one way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On what basis do you want to skip fast?

- Distance of your journey trip?
  The distance is much to short to even shorten the prayer (most sunni madhhabs require a traveling distance of > 80 kilometers, shi'a may have a shorter traveling distance but if I remember well it is still close to 60kilometers), so this trip doesn't even count as traveling! And skipping fast due to travel is only a permission not a due, many scholars say it is better to fast if one is able to do so.
- Duration?
  there's nothing hindering you to take food with you to break your fast once the time for maghrib enters.

It seems to me that there's no valid reason as to why you shouldn't fast. There rather might be a reason as to why you might consider not attending this outing depending on the activities which are planned there.

- [Is it permissible to break a fast if I am travelling?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25525/is-it-permissible-to-break-a-fast-if-i-am-travelling)

Comment: I might even be back home by Iftaar but the day is going to be full of physical activities. I was wondering whether there is such a provision. Thanks for the clarification!